# Apply the "g" tag to a regex pattern in Pykwalify

Tags: python, regex, yaml, pyyaml

I need to create a regex pattern for Pykwalify that only allows characters (`[az]` `[0-9]` `space` `.`), I get it to validate me in a specific order but not to validate for all characters (I can't apply the `g` flag).

This is the regex that I created and that works for me on the https://regexr.com/ platform, but in Pykwalify it doesn't work.

```
/[a-z]|[0-9]|\n|\./g
```

**NOTE:** I need that if there is a character other than those, the Pykwalify test fails. (example: if there is a `-` symbol it should fail the test).

Comment: So, use `^[a-z0-9\n.]*$`

Comment: You SAID space is valid, but your EXAMPLE does not have it.  Instead you substituted \n, which is a newline.